# Displaying what is stored in the cache

Tags: javascript, caching, manifest, offline, html5-appcache

I am currently making a web app and I have used a manifest file to get my web app to work offline. This works great and using Google Chrome, Opera etc I can view what is being cached by right clicking, inspecting the element and viewing the resources.

The problem I have is that I want to view what is stored in the cache in the app when it is being used on an i-pad. I have give this a Google but cant seem to find anything. Is there a way of displaying what is stored in the cache using some JavaScript or JQuery and then having this displayed on a web page within the app.

The app consists of a webview which is currently pulling in other html pages which are being stored in the cache using the manifest. I want to add a simple settings page where what is being stored in the cache can be viewed within the app. Hope that explains enough I would really appreciate any help with this matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to get at this information with JavaScript either, but here are the alternatives I use.

In Mobile Safari, I connect the device to a Mac, open Safari on the Mac, open the site in Mobile Safari or open the native app going to the screen with the UIWebView, go back to the Mac and open the Develop menu. From there you can select the Storage option and view what's in the appcache.

In Chrome, you can view what's stored in the appcache using the URL chrome://appcache-internals/.

If the appcache was saved successfully, you could also simply go to the file itself in your browser.